# About c() predicate in prolog

Tags: prolog

I have the code

> newplan(State, [c(StateList)], [], State):- satisfied( State, StateList).

and I don't know what c() predicate does. I tried to search internet for answers but I couldn't find. Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

In this code `c/1` is just a structure. Prolog is a little different from most languages, in that a structure and a predicate (what might be thought of as a function call in another language) share syntax. So here `c/1` doesn't *do* anything, it's just a marker that (presumably) is granted meaning through something else in the code which you haven't shared with us.

Let me give you a concrete example.

```
eval(c(X), X2) :- X2 is (X*2) + 3.
eval(q(X), X2) :- X2 is X / 3.

something_to_do(c(14)).
something_to_do(q(21)).
```

In this code, `c/1` and `q/1` do not *do* anything. If you query `something_to_do/1` you'll get structures back:

```
?- something_to_do(X).
X = c(14) ;
X = q(21) ;
false.
```

But if you then pass that structure to `eval/2` it does something depending on which structure it gets. So you could say `eval/2` imbues the structure `q/1` and `c/1` with meaning (though "imbuing meaning" is not in any sense official Prolog nomenclature).

```
?- something_to_do(X), eval(X, Y).
X = c(14), Y = 31 ;
X = q(21), Y = 7 ;
false.
```

It's the same story here. You're going to have to search your codebase and find out what `c/1` means in it, because it is not a built-in predicate.

**Note**: it's possible to have structures and predicates with the same name in the same codebase at the same time. For instance, I could add a predicate like

```
q(foo).
q(bar).
q(X) :- even(X).
```

and this predicate does not in any sense overlap with the `q/1` structure above. This is just one of those fun confusing things about Prolog (later on it turns out to be powerful and grand). There is an acute difference between creating structures and attempting to unify goals.